# How did Joy escape?

Tags: plot-explanation, prisoners

The movie *Prisoners* is quite difficult to understand. I am still trying to understand how Joy escaped.

When Joy was in the hospital, it seems that Bob was in her flashback. So did he help her escape?

Do we know where was she found?

Answer (score 4):

The kidnapper Holly Jones mentions that she brought the girls from the underground prison to her house because she was lonely with Alex Jones gone.

Joy's flashback in the hospital indicates that, at some point while they are in the house, Keller Dover shows up for his visit with Holly Jones. Joy and Keller's daughter are both drugged and mostly unconscious, but Joy hears or otherwise senses that Keller is on the property, so that's why she mentions it in the hospital.

Later, the girls somehow managed to make a run for it from the house - but only Joy succeeds in getting away. The flashback shows Joy running through some woods and then arriving at the edge of a freeway, where presumably she was rescued by passers-by.

Comment: This actually doesn't answer the question. The question asks: 
1. How did Joy escape. 2. Do we know where was she found? 3. Did Bob help her escape (why he was in her flashback)?

Comment: Actually, this does answer #2 ("at the edge of a freeway, where presumably she was rescued by passers-by") and #3 ("Joy hears or otherwise senses that Keller is on the property, so that's why she mentions it in the hospital"). I also tried to explain that the movie itself does not provide a clear answer to #1.

Comment: #2 "hear or otherwise senses" is not much informative but OK, that is an answer.
#3 Bob Tyler isn't Keller Dover. I am not sure that the one in a flashback was Bob as OP thinks, but it is certainly not Mrs Jones.

Comment: good point about Bob Tyler... I assume OP meant Keller Dover because in the hospital scene, the girl says to Keller "you were there"